# screen_capture_recorder to record 2nd monitor ffmpeg Win 7

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg, screen, capture, recorder

I use exactly what ffmpeg suggests on the screen_capture_recorder ffmpeg faq to record desktop (located [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop))

ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio=%Device% -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 22050 -t %Duration% out.mkv

works fine. But it records everything. I specifically only want to record what's on the 2nd monitor.

Windows 7 64 bit.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-X11-grabbing), you can offset the screen with this command.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+10,20 /tmp/out.mpg
```

> 0.0 is display.screen number of your X11 server, same as the DISPLAY environment variable. 10 is the x-offset and 20 the y-offset for the
>   grabbing.

So if I wanted to use my right-hand screen I would offset it the number of pixels of my first screen (1366) and specify the size of the screen I intend to record (1920x1080)...

I would use the following command (on debian ubuntu).

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 25 -i :0.0+1366,0 /tmp/out.mpg
```

- `-f x11grab` - Record whole screen
- `-video_size 1920x1080` - Set recordable screen size
- `-framerate 25` - sets the framerate to 25
- `-i :0.0+1366,0` - Uses screen 0, offset/padded by 1366 pixels to the left
- `/tmp/out.mpg` - output file location

Answer (score 1):

What you may have to do is specify exactly what to grab, with `-offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080` grabs your first screen starting at the top left of your monitor layout if your first screen has a resolution of 1920x1080 or you can do `-offset_x 1920 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080` to shift the start point right 1920 pixels and record size of 1920x1080.

Comment: these parameters are for "gdigrab" not for "screen-capture-recorder". as https://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free/blob/master/README.adoc here , you should change registry settings.

Comment: If the second monitor is on the left of the first one, *negative* values are the way to go: `-offset_x -1920` for example.